# Fragment is not assignable to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest, android-activity

- Attempts to switch activities between two Android Fragments is failing.
- This happens in spite of using the Android doco example verbatim:

[Android Fragment doco](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

- Attempts to add the target Fragment to the AndroidManifest.xml does not compile with the same message that is in the Title of this question.
- If I hack the same process using only Views and straight Activities the all is well.
- If I leave the AndroidManifest.xml unchanged then I get a run-time exception with the question:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {name.davidwbrown.actionbartabs/name.davidwbrown.actionbartabs.UserDetailsFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining an xml layout containing the fragment instead of assigning it to the `<activity>` tag on the manifest. Then use `findViewById(R.id.frameId)` to find it in code and then attach it to the activity. In the manifest, keep the activity tag something similar to this and it should work:

```
<activity
        android:name="name.davidwbrown.actionbartabs.UserDetailsFragment"
        android:label="@string/activity_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thnx 4 the speedy reply. Unfortunately, AdroidManifest.xml is not happy notwithstanding as follows: `<activity android:name="name.davidwbrown.actionbartabs.UserDetailsFragment"
                  android:label="@string/tvFragment">
        </activity>` and here is the error msg: `name.david.actionbartabs.UserDetailsFragment is not assignable to android.app.Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try changing your `Fragment` class to a `FragmentActivity` class.